# Is there any way to access a user's device via the JS Bluetooth API when the device is already connected to their computer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have some JS/React code that allows a user to give my AI access to a micro:bit robot via Bluetooth, when the user clicks a Connect button:

```
 const connectClicked = async () => {
    try {
      // Request Bluetooth device
      const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(
        {acceptAllDevices: true}
      );
      setMicrobitDevice(device);

      // Connect to GATT server
      await device.gatt.connect();

      // ...etc.
```

When the user reloads the page, I lose the connection. In testing, my Mac remains connected to the device. In fact, even when I call `microbitDevice.gatt.disconnect()` when they click my Disconnect button, my Mac either retains the connection or instantly reconnects (it does this instant reconnection when I click Disconnect on my OS Bluetooth settings too). I have to click Forget Device to make it stop.

The problem this creates is that `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice` only displays non-connected devices. As far as I understand it, this method does two things at once: shows available devices, and asks permission for my code to use them. Even if I try to save the device object, I will need new permission on a reload--and I believe the only way to get it via Bluetooth API is via `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice`.

Can someone please help me? Is my understanding wrong; is there a way with the Bluetooth API to get permission to use a connected device, or retain permission once given it, on reload? Or is there another way using another API? Thank you.